# How do I print out raw string which contain tags in PHP?

Tags: php

For example:

```
$str="<script>alert('hello');</script>";
```

If I use echo to print it out, it will pop up an alert window in the browser.

How can I print out the raw string `<script>alert('hello');</script>` in this case?

Comment: Do you want the RAW tags/content, or do you want it to look like real content but with replaced `<` `>` ?

Comment: <script></script> also should be output

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Depends if you want the words `script` in. If yes, then

You should use this.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If not just use `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: all your functions dont output the raw tags. (REAL "<", ">" chars)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `htmlspecialchars`

```
$str = htmlspecialchars( "<script>alert('hello');</script>" )
```

docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php